# Wrong return from Web API .NET Core 2.0 using bearer token from AppAuth

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c

Im using AppAuth to acquire my access token to consume my web API but when i make the request from Unity Android(HTTPRequest) using the [Authorization] field on my header, i receive an HTML instead of the JSON inside my API.

Here's my API

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Values")]
[Authorize]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
  CosmosDatabaseConnection cdc = CosmosDatabaseConnection.Instance;

// GET: api/Values
[HttpGet]
public JValue Get()
 {
   AppState appState = SessionManager.GetCookieSession(HttpContext.Session, 
    User);
   return new JValue ( appState.User.profile.ToString() );
 }
}
```

Here's my Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace Rbxsoft
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddAzureAdB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options))
        .AddCookie();

        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions =>
        {
            jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        });
        services.AddSwaggerGen();

        // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache.
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            //options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000000);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.Name = ".Rbxsoft.Session";
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseSession();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        StaticFileOptions option = new StaticFileOptions();
        FileExtensionContentTypeProvider contentTypeProvider = (FileExtensionContentTypeProvider)option.ContentTypeProvider ??
        new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
        contentTypeProvider.Mappings.Add(".unityweb", "application/octet-stream");
        option.ContentTypeProvider = contentTypeProvider;
        app.UseStaticFiles(option);

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUi();
    }
}
}
```

When i make the request using my bearer token, i receive an HTML instead of the users profile(JSON). My code should be able to authenticate a user on my Website and my Mobile Application using Azure AD B2C, but i can only make it work when consume my API from the browser.

Comment: I suggest that track the request sending from android client and compare it with the request sending from browser. You can use the Fiddler to tack the HTTP request.

Comment: What is the HTML content?

Comment: Here's the HTML https://ufile.io/9qmd5